# Making a newline within JAVA

Tags: java, youtube-api

I do not if I am doing this right or I am missing something. When I implement the following to create a new line within my YouTube descriptions they are not coming out right.

```
private static final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
mg.getDescription().setHtmlContent("This is line one." + newLine + "This is line two." + newLine + newLine + "This is line three.");
```

**This how it comes out within the YouTube Description**

> This is line one.
>  This is line two. This is
>  line three.

*When it should be coming out as this.*

> This is line one.
>  This is line two.
>  This is
>   line three.

I sort of think I am not doing something right here; if I am not getting the right layout as my end result.

Comment: What type is `mg`? Looking around in the APIs, I see that at least in some places, `setDescription(String)` is getting replaced with `setSummary(TextConstruct)`. For example, https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/BaseEntry#setSummary(com.google.gdata.data.TextConstruct)

Comment: I have written a script to upload using PHP along with the Zend Framework. Unfortunately when posting tags they cannot be two word or longer (no white space). I switched to JAVA recently and used this site as guideline. http://java.dzone.com/announcements/getting-started-youtube-java mg means Media Group. I shorten it when written my version. It works perfectly except for the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a newline won't actually create a line break in HTML. You instead need to use the `<br />` tag.

Comment: Does YouTube API allow <br /> when posting descriptions? As I read you were not allowed to use open and closed < > brackets.

Comment: Also, if newlines don't create a line break, then why does the current results have a line break between the first and second line?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the YouTube API. The method is called `setHtmlContent`, which to me suggests that it's expecting HTML rather than plain text. If this is wrong then I don't know what's going on (though you might try `\r\n`, as that's the line break for HTTP).

Comment: I do not know about it does for the first one and never the second or third ones. Which is why I am here - thinking I did something wrong.

Comment: I will try both `\r\n` and `<br />` and see if any of those work.

Comment: yes, you can use <br /> or '\n'. but newlines don't create a new line.

Comment: Place `<br />` line breaks into my description produced the appropriate newlines that I required. Perfectly, thanks!